# How to deploy two PHP applications in a single instance in amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, github, travis-ci

I recently started using AWS services.

I have a symfony 3 application running on EBS - using a single EC2 instance (with Linux AMI) with EIP configured and publicly accessible to a client. I've deployed this to EBS via making a pipeline with Github and pushing the code via Travis-CI.

I want to run another PHP application - [OSTicket](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket)(rather hosted) in the same instance so that it can be accessible by the EBS public URL as a subdomain. 
How can I achieve this all the while keeping the continuous integration ?

Comment: Well, You can easily create a workflow and deploy Symfony application on amazon servers with few click. You can follow the article and after deployment you can connect it with github and work on pipelines. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/host-symfony-on-aws/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using apache, you want to set up name-based virtual host entries. (nginx has something similar)

Then you can have two different configs, pointing to different docroots, something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1.example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  ErrorLog logs/site1_error.log
  CustomLog logs/site1_access.log
  <Directory "/var/www/html/site1">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site2.example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  ErrorLog logs/site2_error.log
  CustomLog logs/site2_access.log
  <Directory "/var/www/html/site2">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: how do we add ssl to these different folder / apps, i've created 2 virtual hosts *:80 and *:81

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 directories inside /var/www/html folder named site1 and site2.
Navigate to the 000-default.conf file inside the folder /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Add the directory of second website with value of virtualhost with a different port number.

Then go to ports.conf file inside apache2 directory and add Listen

That'll help you in running 2 different PHP apps on same instance of EC2.

Comment: Will this have an affect as I'm using Travis CI for code push ? I mean will I have to configure the instance in each build in this way ?